# Export list of shapely.geometry.polygons as Esri shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, geometry, osgeo

I have a list of shapely polygons, `polygons`. I want to export them all to an Esri shapefile layer. Here is the first feature in the list of polygons:

POLYGON ((484 169, 485 169, 485 170, 486 170, 486 171, 487 171, 487 170, 488 170, 488 169, 490 169, 490 170, 492 170, 492 172, 494 172, 494 178, 493 178, 493 179, 492 179, 492 180, 487 180, 487 179, 485 179, 485 176, 484 176, 484 171, 483 171, 483 170, 484 170, 484 169))

There is documentation describing how to do this at various sources such as [this one](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-layer-from-the-extent-of-an-existing-layer), however I am having trouble implementing it. Here is the code from the above documentation which I have tried to apply to my dataset:

```
#A binary array (not actually my array though)
filtered_labels = np.array([1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1])

#init generator
shapes = rio.features.shapes(filtered_labels)

# get srs
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(spatial_image.GetProjection())

#create polygons. "Ploygons" is a list of polygons
polygons = [shapely.geometry.Polygon(shape[0]["coordinates"][0]) for shape in shapes if shape[1] == 1]

polygon = polygons[0]

# Here is where the converting and exporting starts
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Save extent to a new Shapefile
outShapefile = "C:\\Users\\maxduso.stu\\Desktop\\FCOR_599\\project_work\\data\\shapes\\cds.shp"
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

# Remove output shapefile if it already exists
if os.path.exists(outShapefile):
    outDriver.DeleteDataSource(outShapefile)

# Create the output shapefile
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource(outShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer('cds',
                            srs = spatial_image.GetSpatialRef())

# Add an ID field
idField = ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTInteger)
outLayer.CreateField(idField)

# Create the feature and set values
featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
feature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(polygon.wkb)
feature.SetGeometry(geom)
feature.SetField("id", 1)
outLayer.CreateFeature(feature)
feature = None

# Save and close DataSource
inDataSource = None
outDataSource = None
```

Oddly, the error I receive alternates between:

`TypeError: in method 'Feature_SetGeometry', argument 2 of type 'OGRGeometryShadow *'`

and

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'`

I honestly don't even have a theory as to what is going wrong because I don't understand how all the feature creations work. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily save them to a shapefile using geopandas.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# polygons sample
polygons = [Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]),
            Polygon([(2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 2)])]


crs = 'epsg:4326' # change here to crs of the coordinates
outShapefile = 'c:/test/test.shp'

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs, geometry=polygons)
gdf.to_file(outShapefile)
```

This is the answer to "*I have shapely polygons and need to export to a shapefile*".

---

To get crs from a source (in your script)

```
import osgeo.osr as osr

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(spatial_image.GetProjection())

# crs = "EPSG:EPSG_CODE"
crs = f"{srs.GetAuthorityName(None)}:{srs.GetAuthorityCode(None)}" 

...
```

Comment: fantastic! Yes though that the way I was going about it seemed over complicated but this method did not come up in my research. Thank you!

Comment: If I want the image to line up with basemaps I will have to store the image extent as well as the crs right? @Kadir Sahbaz

Comment: You can save it as GeoTiff.

Comment: So add geotiff as an intermediate step between the numpy array and the shapely polygon creation? I guess this would convert the pixel units to meters (because my coordinate system is in meters) instead of pixel row/column eh? After which the polygon coordinate pairs would be in those same units? I supposed this should work as long as shapely can create polygons from a geotiff. Thanks for all your help! I did ask another question regarding extent at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/454429/set-the-crs-and-spatial-extent-of-output-shapefile-derived-from-raster-surface